# how to cut only "test2-test" from string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

how to cut word "test2-test" from var="./test3/test2-test-10.23-67.tar.gz"

"test2-test" could be any name,
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide some more examples of filenames?  If "test2-test" could be any name, you'll likely need to use regex here.  What is the format of the file name?

Comment: like var="./dir1/dir2/dir3/file-11.22.33.tar.gz"

Comment: like var="./dir1/dir2/dir3/fileName-11.22.33.tar.gz"
now I want to "fileName" from var,I don't know the "fileName" at run time. so I cant match directly "fileName" in the given string.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want as a result `./test3/10.23-67.tar.gz` or do you want as a result `test2-test`?

Comment: input-"./dir1/dir2/dir3/fileName-11.22.33.tar.gz"
output- "fileName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @Carloluis is nice, but I think the question was not properly framed.

@Samresh wanted to remove the extra part from `./test3/test2-test-10.23-67.tar.gz` so that only **test2-test** remained.

It can be done by following -

```
basename ./test3/test2-test-10.23-67.tar.gz | sed 's/-[[:digit:]].*//'
```

'basename' will strip the path out, so only the filename (test2-test) remains.
Next, sed can match a regex. So we match the version and file extension and replace it with empty string.

This works for bash 4.2.46.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly I was looking

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring replacement like this:

```
var="./test3/test2-test-10.23-67.tar.gz"
echo ${var/test2-test/}
```

Output: `./test3/-10.23-67.tar.gz`

Read more about [manipulating strings](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

---

Updating answer to keep only the filename in the path using string replacing and [basename](https://ss64.com/bash/basename.html):

```
basename ${var/-[0-9]*.*/}
```

Output: `test2-test`

Comment: @Samresh You're welcome. I just updated the answer to keep only the fileName in the path as you explain in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Avi is nice, but a little slow. Pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="./test3/test2-test-10.23-67.tar.gz"
var=${var##*/}
var=${var%%-[0-9]*}
echo $var
```

100 times faster with 10000 iterations

```
bash   <  sed+basename (no builtin command)
129 ms < 13006 ms
```